# How to create dynamic table in dbml file?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm using linq to sql. I have a table in dbml file that some of its fields can be generate dynamically (at run time). Is there any way to add fields to a table dynamiccaly , or add a class to dbml file dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a class to the DBML file dynamically, but you can create a [`TypeBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx) instance to create a class at runtime with the appropriate [`TableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx) and [`ColumnAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.aspx) attributes and then use *that* class in your queries.

The problem with this is that you have to access this through reflection, including most of the calls to generate the queries (since you have no way of knowing at compile time what to call those members).

That said, your best bet would be to use a more generic container (depending on your data shape) and then project that into a sequence of [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) instances (or some other structure) which would hold the value keyed on the name of the dynamic field.

Comment: Thank you . In regards to your answer, Here is the link that I have found really usefull

http://blog.bodurov.com/How-to-Bind-Silverlight-DataGrid-From-IEnumerable-of-IDictionary